# Inconstant Bandwidth despite Bandwidth Limitation in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04, virtualbox-networking, bandwidth, iperf

In VirtualBox, I have two Ubuntu 18.04 VMs running on an Ubuntu 18.04 host. My target is to simulate network traffic between the two VMs (one as a Server, one as a Client). Therefore I set the VM adapter settings to **Internal Network**. So basically, there are just these two VMs on two different static IP addresses and that's it.

Now I want to limit the available bandwidth for that connection. Therefore I used the VirtualBox command **bandwidthctl** in the Host terminal to limit the available bandwidth for both VMs to 300mbit/s:

```
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM-Server" add LimitServer --type network --limit 300m 
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM-Client" add LimitClient --type network --limit 300m
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM-Server" --nicbandwidthgroup1 LimitServer
VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM-Client" --nicbandwidthgroup1 LimitClient
```

Then I used **iPerf** to check the maximum bandwidth. After starting it on the Server-VM (iPerf -s) I tried the following on the Client-VM:

```
iperf -c 192.168.0.2 -t 20  -i 10
```

what leads to a duration time of 20 seconds (-t 20) and an interval of 10 seconds (-i 10) between each bandwidth report.

The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O4Ce.png) was an average bandwidth of **302mbit/s in the interval of 0-10seconds** and **298mbit/s in the interval of 10-20 seconds**.

Now I changed the interval time from 10 seconds to 0.5 seconds. The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Righ.png) was a very inconstant bandwidth from e.g **287mbit/s in the interval of 6.0-6.5 seconds** or **319mbit/s in the interval of 3.5-4.0 seconds**.

Changing the interval time to 0.1 seconds made it even worse and the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQsel.png) was **161mbit/s from 1.4-1.5 seconds** and then **412mbit/s from 1.5-1.6 seconds**.

The average bandwidth over the whole duration time of 20 seconds was always something about 300mbit/s but my question is:

**Why do I get an inconstant bandwidth in the intervals between despite adjusting a limitation of 300mbit/s?**